# What do we mean by a Free-particle solution to Dirac equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, interactions

I read this part in Peskin,QFT. And I'm confused about the terminology "free-particle solution", I don't know what does it mean.
If by free-particle it means no interaction, then the Lagrangian from which we get Dirac equation has no interaction term! Then I'll assume by free-particle solution, there also exist nonfree solution or interacting solution?
It's true that in QM, free particle solution of Schrodinger equation is plane wave, but that is wave function, here we are talking about classical field, why we still assume free solution is plane wave?

Comment: The meaning is given in the mathematics. Here it probably means the interaction terms have been dropped, with a view to getting some general insight into the nature of the field without them.

Answer (score 0):

> here we are talking about classical field, why we still assume free solution is plane wave?

QFT means Quantum Field Theory. The simplest quantum field theory is to posit fields as the free particle  wave function, i.e. no potential,  of some quantum equation, on which creation and annihilation operators act. The fields by construction are not classical, are not measurable and are defined in conjunction with creation and annihilation operators. The method is applied more widely than in particle physics.

The [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) is expressed as a QFT. Every elementary particle in the table of particles defines a field which is mathematically written as the free particle wavefunction, i.e. no potentials, of the corresponding equation: Dirac for fermions, Klein Gordon for bosons, q[uantized maxwell](http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002?ln=en) for the photons. On these the creation and annihilation operators can define the interactions between the particles, the Feynman diagrams representing the integrals that give crossections and decays.

Quantum field theory is quantum because it depends on the basic wave functions of quantum equations and thus the [postulates of quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I will keep thinking about it, maybe the terminology isn't a big deal.

Answer (score -1):

What can an electron interact with? Plenty of things, EM fields being one. When you write down the Dirac Lagrangian, do you include a term for this EM field? Or anything else; let's be wild and say gravity. You don't.

So, is the electron interacting with anything? No; and thus it is, by definition, free. You have written down the Lagrangian for a FREE electron-one not subject to any interactions. The corresponding hamiltonian contains no interaction terms.

As another example; consider the Klein Gordon Lagrangian. These are 'free' waves(so you have nice properties like superposition). Now, add a $\phi^4$ term. This represents a (self)interaction, and the solutions to the equations of motion coming from here will NOT be free particles.

You could now, for instance, introduce now a coupling with EM field; you end up with the QED lagrangian(you have to introduce a covariant derivative etc, but that's details). This is NOT the Dirac Lagrangian, and it's solutions are NOT free particles-they are fermions INTERACTING with photons.